# How to control the order of fetching when fetching all remotes by git fetch --all

Tags: git, git-fetch

I have a lot of remotes added in my git. Each remote is a link to a network share folder of different regions, and each remote contains the code submitted by one developer.

Everyday I need to fetch the latest code they submitted by *git fetch --all*.

Because of the geographical location, the speed of the network share folders are different. Some of them are very very slow. I want to fetch the data from the fastest share folder first so that I can start examining code while waiting for the fetching of other remotes.

The order of fetch by *git fetch --all* is not the same as the one shown by *git remote -v*. How is the order of fetching determined and is there a way to control the order?

Comment: Easiest is to put the fastest ones in a text file and `{ cat fastestones; git remote; } | while read; do git fetch $REPLY; done` -- you'll double-fetch the fast ones but so what?  I don't think `git remote` has any required listing order.

Comment: Best would probably be to have one local repo per developer with just the one remote, start all those fetches in parallel, then do a fetch --all from the local ones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's simply the order they appear in `.git/config`. It's just a text file, I edit it all the time.

Answer (score 6):

```
git config remotes.default "faster slower"
```

Then subsequent `git remote update`, or `git fetch --all`, will always update the remotes in the specified order, i.e., first `faster`, then `slower`.

#### Note:

- It's `remotes`, with an ending `'s'`.
- Here `default` is the group name, other names are OK, but then need to be specified, like `git remote update <group>`. `default` happens to be the default group name if not specified.

Alternatively, in the early implementation, as `git fetch --all` (used also by `git remote update`) processes remotes in the order they appear in `.git/config`, thus you can change the order in `.git/config` to do the trick. But this is not part of the API, therefore could be broken when the implementation detail changes, as [**@chwarr** has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26373995#comment-61409550).

Comment: With git version 2.8.1.windows.1, I do not observe that `git fetch --all` uses the order in `remotes.default`. It's using the order in `.git\config`.

`git remote update` does use the order in `remotes.default`.